# How to set background color for series with unique name in Gantt chart from Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I want to dynamically show background colors for each Series (Unique names) in gantt chart. Something like shown in below below screenshot

[Image showing light grey and grey background for Development & Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB5AS.png)

I tried plotBands option on yAxis by referring this [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.plotBands)

[Codepen link for the demo code](https://codepen.io/manshi44/pen/OJaXOOr)

```
 yAxis: 
      {
       uniqueNames: true,
       plotBands: [
            {
                color: "#DCDCDC",
                from: 0.5,
                to: 1.5
            },
           {
                color: "grey",
                from: 1.5,
                to: 2.5
            }
        ],
    },
```

With this i can set background if i know from and to values. But in my case these values are gonna be dyanamic.

So is there a way I can set background for series with uniqueNames = true ?

Comment: It's unclear how you update your chart dynamically, but I suppose you are using the api, e.g., class [GanntChart](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.GanttChart); so why not use the same api to update the plotBands? In particular if `ganttChart` is the chart instance (the result of the call to `Highcharts.ganttChart`) you can set the plotBands as `ganttChart.yAxis?.addPlotBand({....})`, with the same argument as the "static" option. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpk0oeq8/)uses a standard doc example and sets a plotBand after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, there is no option in the API that allows you to set the background for a given row, the `plotBands` you used is a good way but not ideal if you want to have it dynamic.

In such a situation, you can use SVGRenderer and use the callback function `chart.events.load()` to generate rectangles and then use `chart.events.render()` to dynamically update their position and height when changing the window width or other chart updates.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jarqk03c/

**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thanks Michal it works for me now :)
You guys are prompt. Thanks again for real quick response